# Change the interval of the outputted abilities in mirt

Tags: r

I'm using `mirt`and `mirtCAT` libraries to obtain student's trait scores with an unidimensional dichotomic 3 parameters logistic model (in witch the items are already callibrated).

How can I change the trait scale interval outputted by `fscores`? More explicitly, given the vector `F1` containing the scores of the `N` test takers, how to enforce that every entry of `F1` is a member of a interval whose extremes are a < b?

I'm using the following code to get the abilities:

```
library(mirt)
library(mirtCAT)
test <- read.csv(test.csv)
par <- read.csv(par.csv)
a1 <- c(par[,1])
d <- c(par[,2])
g <- c(par[,3])
par <- data.frame(a1,d,g)
mod <- generate.mirt_object(parameters=par,itemtype='3PL')
scores <- fscores(mod,response.pattern=test)
```

Witch produces abilities from minus infinity to infinity. The [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mirt/mirt.pdf) does not mention this, but is quite common in IRT analysis for interpretation reasons.

Comment: (1) the example is not replicable. (2) Why would you want to do that? Do you have reason to assume that estimates outside of that interval are invalid? (3) Typically you don't. The reason why ability estimates in the range from - infinity to infinity are produced is more due to a central assumption of the IRT models: that is, the factor scores in IRT models are assumed to be realisations of a normal distrubtion which is unbound by definition.

Comment: There is an option for this in the `fscores()` documentation. See the argument `max_theta`, which is capped at 20 for numerical stability reasons. Though I would recommend first computing the unbounded estimates first, and then applying your a < b after these are computed.